# How to show in toolbox a UserControl that is from another solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, user-controls

**Background:**

I have a "Solution 1" (VS solution), with 1 WinForms project, and 1 class library project that contains my `UserControl` in question, which supposedly can be used on any projects applicable. I then have a "Solution 2", which contains a WinForms project.

**Scenario:**

1. On a project on the same "Solution 1", I reference the `UserControl` DLL, and it shows up on the toolbox. → Expected behavior
2. On a project on "**Solution 2**", I reference the DLL but **it doesn't show up on the toolbox**. → **Unexpected behavior**

**Things I did:**

1. I have set `[ToolboxItem(true)]`
2. Ensured that Tools > Options > Windows Forms Designer > General : Automatically Populate Toolbox is true.
3. Rebuild the project many times already.
4. Restarted VS many times already.
5. Even restarted my PC.
6. Tested with both VS2019 and 2015.

**Question:**

1. Is this really the correct behavior, for outside-solution-libraries to not automatically show up in the toolbox?
2. And, is the only way to make `UserControls` show in the toolbox on this scenario is "Choose items" menu in the Toolbox?
3. Anybody else experiencing the same thing?

If the answer to both questions is no, what then are the missing steps to make my `UserControl` show up in this other solution?

Comment: Check the dll in `\bin\Debug` folder, or clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: @KyleWang I did that also. Please see the updated post.

Comment: Maybe you can right click on the toolbox, select "Choose Items.." and browse to the 
usercontrol dll.